# How to fix : 'IDataProtectionBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'PersistKeysToDbContext' and no accessible extension

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am attempting to persist Keys to SQL using the PersistKeysToDbContext extension from services.AddDataProtection(). At the moment we are using PersistKeysToStackExchangeRedis which works really well, however a need was identitied to move it to DB instead.

We are using a .net Core 2.2 project having added the following references:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.0)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions (2.2.0)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.StackExchangeRedis (2.2.0) *(obviously for current functionality)*
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (2.2.0)

```
services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

I get the following error from the compiler:

'IDataProtectionBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'PersistKeysToDbContext' and no accessible extension method 'PersistKeysToDbContext' accepting a first argument of type 'IDataProtectionBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you want to have reference to nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore, Note the Core not .net framework

Comment: Apologies - I had that reference. I've omitted the "Core" part in the question. I've updated the question.

Comment: Can you post the whole startup code inluding using statements also it would help if you can provide nuget file contents

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Make sure you have Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions + Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.EntityFrameworkCore installed (as references).

2) Add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;` to Startup.cs (or wherever you have the problem).

I've tested and it works, so if it still doesn't work, you probably need to make sure you haven't missed anything.